# c++ do while condition is not work as expected

Tags: c++

I wonder why `while (selection != 'q' && selection != 'Q')` works but `while (selection != 'q' || selection != 'Q')` does not work.  It will never terminate the loop. When I use `else if (selection == 'q' || selection == 'Q' )` (with `||`) it's working fine. Can someone help?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char selection{};
    do{
        cout << "\n--------------------------"<< endl;
        cout << "1.Do this" << endl;
        cout << "2.Do that" << endl;
        cout << "3.Do something else" << endl;
        cout << "4.Quit" << endl;
        cout << "\nEnter your selection" << endl;
        cin >> selection;

        if (selection == '1')
            cout << "You chose 1 - doing this" << endl;
        else if (selection == '2')
            cout << "You chose 2 - doing that" << endl;
        else if (selection == '3')
            cout << "You chose 3 - doing  something else" << endl;
        else if (selection == 'q' || selection == 'Q' )
            cout << "Goodbye" << endl;
        else
            cout << "Unknown option -- try again" << endl;
    }
    while (selection != 'q' && selection != 'Q');
}
```

Comment: i think if i implement while (selection != 'q' || selection != 'Q'); => this will be true if i only press q lowercase or Q uppercase so it will not terminate loop if i use or ||.
 , if i implement while (selection != 'q' && selection != 'Q'); => and i press only q or Q this will be false in this case and it will terminates the loop.. do i understand that in correct way???

Comment: The second case can never be false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look at your proposed condition, which you are wondering why it doesn't work:

```
while (selection != 'q' || selection != 'Q')
```

In order for this `while` loop to terminate the loop, the above expression must evaluate to false. That's how a `while` loop works. In other words:

```
!(selection != 'q' || selection != 'Q')
```

must be true. Basic rules of boolean logic show that this expression is logically equivalent to

```
selection == 'q' && selection == 'Q'
```

which, obviously can never happen. The `selection` value can never be `q` and `Q` at the same time. Only [Schrödinger's cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat) can do that.

Comment: thank you for your help :) , really appreciate that

Answer (score 1):

To add onto the answer. you could also use `!(selection == 'q' || selection == 'Q')` where in this case, when `q`, `!(true||false)=false` and when `Q`, `!(false||true)=false` and everything else, `!(false||false)=true`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char selection{};
    do{
        cout << "\n--------------------------"<< endl;
        cout << "1.Do this" << endl;
        cout << "2.Do that" << endl;
        cout << "3.Do something else" << endl;
        cout << "4.Quit" << endl;
        cout << "\nEnter your selection" << endl;
        cin >> selection;

        if(selection == '1')
            cout << "You chose 1 - doing this" << endl;
        else if(selection == '2')
            cout << "You chose 2 - doing that" << endl;
        else if (selection == '3')
            cout << "You chose 3 - doing  something else" << endl;
        else if (selection == 'q' || selection == 'Q' ){
            cout << "Goodbye" << endl;
            break; //break in case of 'Q'||'q'
        }
        else
            cout << "Unknown option -- try again" << endl;
    }while(true);
```

Just to add on to the explanation already answered. This works as well.